# How can I swipe between tabs using Polymer 1.0?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I am using Polymer 1.0 and looking to create a tabbed layout where I can swipe between each tab I have. I have found a [swipe-pages](http://theseamau5.github.io/swipe-pages/components/swipe-pages/demo.html) component, but the dependencies on the site state that it needs `"polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^0.4.0"` which does not work with the rest of my application. Are there any other components compatible with the latest version of Polymer (or at least Polymer 1.0)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Polymer 1.0 version. See https://github.com/slogger/swipe-pages.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very new in web development but I made an swipeable-pages element for Polymer 1.0 that works with dynamic pages like dom-repeat!

https://github.com/emersonbottero/swipeable-pages.

P.S.: I know the question is old but people may still need it.
P.S.2: Improvements are welcome to the code :D.