# Swipeable Tabs with Polymer JS 2

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

Is there a simple way to implement swipeable tabs using Polymer JS 2 in which navigation can be performed using tab selection or container swiping?

Ideally there's a component or combination of components already built for this.  However, I haven't been able to find any that meet the need directly.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32972768/how-can-i-swipe-between-tabs-using-polymer-1-0) for Polymer JS 1, however, I'm looking for a Polymer JS 2 solution.

If needed, I can write my own. I would think these elements would be the starting point but not sure:

- [paper-tabs](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-tabs)
- [iron-swipeable-container](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-swipeable-container)

Any thoughts?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing and found this thread. So far I don't have an answer.